# Issue with android application MobileMoney

Tags: java, android, android-activity, crash

I'm facing an issue with this application in my xiaomi mi 6x

The app developer says the issue is at my side. I'm not sure what should I do.

Here is the error that I receive when I open the app and it closes and shows the below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cac.mobilemoney.app/cac.mobilemoney.app.ui.LoginActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class c.a.a.n.c
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3082)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1832)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6821)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class c.a.a.n.c
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(Unknown Source:391)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(Unknown Source:244)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(Unknown Source:14)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source:7)
    at cac.mobilemoney.app.ui.LoginActivity.onCreate(:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What information should I add?